# Why are the messages getting lost at random from the service bus? What is it that I am doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, azure, queue, azure-servicebus-queues

What is the correct way to continuously receive messages from the Azure Service Bus? I do the following by polling the queue infinitely.

```
const receiver = queueClient.createReceiver(ReceiveMode.peekLock);
while (true) {
    const maxMessageCount = 1;
    try {
        if (!receiver.isReceivingMessages()) {
            const message = await receiver.receiveMessages(maxMessageCount);
            if (message.length > 0) {
                /**
                 * Note: we are always receiving one message per call
                 */
                processMessage(message[0]);
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        processError(err);
    }
}
```

But I am hitting a very weird situation. After some time, half of the messages get lost and only half are received by the above receiver. I wonder what is happening. Is there some bug in this code? I usually start the nodejs script and stop it using ctrl+c. Is there a possibility of some deamon listner running in the background with the above logic even when I have stopped the nodejs script?

Note: I always start a single nodejs script.

Comment: I was starting to make an answer to @sean that I was facing similar weird situation since we've upgraded from rest api to native node library ... then performed a last double check on TTL and ... some senders added it without notice.

Answer (score 2):

Messages are never lost with Azure Service Bus. As your code is using `PeekLock` mode, most likely the messages get retried and eventually end up in the dead-letter queue. Check the dead letter queue to see if they are there. Alternatively, verify that time to live (`TTL`) is not set to something short and causes messages to be purged.